# How to param binding with asp .net mvc when there's dot in the name?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following code in my view

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="dev" value="foobar" />
```

In the controller I have

```
public ActionResult BobLobLaw(string dev)
```

The above works well. But then I changed my view model, now my view code becomes like

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="arrested.dev" value="foobar" />
```

How should I name my action param so that it will bind to the new input name ("arrested.dev") ?

Additionally, looking on how to do this for enum type as well. e.g.

```
<% Html.DropDownList("arrested.devEnum", SelectList) %>

public ActionResult BobLobLaw2(suitEnum arrested.devEnum)
```

Answer (score 0):

The modelbinder interprets a `.` to mean a property on an object. So you would need some object with a property of `dev` as a parameter:

```
public class Arrested
{
    public string dev { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
public ActionResult BobLobLaw(Arrested arrested)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, great answer. However, I find it that for dropdownlist it does not work. I bind my dropdownlist to an enum type. Any clue how to make it work?